# result on ordering data is not as I expected

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried this to sort result on form submit based on cells value (progressive numbers)

```
function ordina() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].
  sort(4,false).sort(8,false).sort(7,false);
}
```

it almost works but result are not in the correct sequence (01--> 03 --> 02..  instead of 01-->02-->03..)

what I'm missing??!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand your current issue from your showing script and `it almost works but result are not in the correct sequence (01--> 03 --> 02.. instead of 01-->02-->03..)`. Can I ask you about the details of it? For example, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Answer (score 0):

See this page of support: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/16556745/google-spreadsheet-script-how-to-sort-a-range-of-data

When you chain multiple `sort()` on the same sheet, the final `sort` has the highest importance.

So if what you want to achieve is "sort by column C then by column B then by column A" this results to `sheet.sort(3).sort(2).sort(1)` in Apps Script

If you need more help, please edit your post and show us how the sheet looks like after your sort.